# UDP Last Data received timeout from different sources

Tags: c#, udp

i have a C# Winform that is accepting UDP Packets from several devices a single port.

The devices sent UDP packets to me at a set interval and i want to implement a way to know when a device has stopped sending packets.

I use a single UDPClient and using the Receive function. When data is received, i pass the RemoteIPEndPoint back to my mainform to update values.

What would be the best way to this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little abstract questions and there could be many solutions to that. One simple and quick solution would be to create a HashTable where,
HashKey = IP of Remote device
Value = Timestamp when last packet received from that device.

Now whenever you receive a packet you just update the hashtable like

if (hashTable contains "RemoteEndPoint")
{
 hashTable [ remoteEndPoint ] = now() // current Time.
}
else
{
 // if you want to add/register new device to your list, do it here
}

Beside that you can just run a Timer with some interval that traverse the HashTable and check if some TimeStamp is less then (currentTime - Your Set Interval), then you can say that you haven't received the data from that end point.